# syntax issue with bash function in alias

Tags: bash, function, syntax, alias

I can't figure out why my syntax is wrong here:

```
alias lookup='function lookup(){ echo "Unqiue ID: $1"; ldapsearch -x -h domain -b 'ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com' uid='$1'}'
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What problem do you have? Why do you define function in alias?

Comment: I am trying to pass a parameter into a ldapsearch.

Comment: Two quote-related problems: you can't nest single quotes inside other single quotes, and you even if you could, you aren't closing the outermost single quote after the closing `}`.

Comment: Also, all `lookup` does is define a function; you aren't calling it, and aliases don't take parameters at all.

Comment: i was told the only way I could pass a parameter from stdin to a alias was a function is that not correct ? Also @chepner I do have a ' at the end for some reason when posting this it didn't carry over.

Comment: You aren't using standard input here at all. The "trick" to make an alias take a parameter requires you to then immediately call the function: `alias lookup='function lookup () { ...}; lookup'`, but doing so is generally pointless because you are redefining the function every time you call it, and you are defining a function to, er, avoid defining a function.

Comment: @Dk6861636b If you want to define something that takes parameter(s) in a reasonable fashion, use a function *instead of* an alias (not *with* or *in* an alias).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an alias here at all; just define the function:

```
lookup () {
    echo "Unqiue ID: $1"
    ldapsearch -x -h domain -b 'ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com' uid="$1"
}
```

Be sure to use double quotes, not single quotes, to allow `$1` to expand.

The only reason to use an alias as well would be if you wanted to give the function a long name for self-documenting purposes, then define a more user-friendly alias, say, `alias lu=lookup`.